# Trying to add or replace things in the Fax Field of Active Directory using Powershell If statements

Tags: powershell, if-statement, active-directory

I have a list of users exported to a csv. Some of them have fax numbers, some of them do not. To add the number I need in there, I have this written:

```
$users = Import-Csv C:\ (My CSV path)

ForEach($user in $users) {
    if(Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties fax -eq $null) {
        Set-ADUser $user.samaccountname -add @{fax=$($user.fax)}
    }
    else {
        Set-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Replace @{fax=$($user.fax)}
    }
}
```

The error I get for this is:

> -Properties : The term '-Properties' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use `if ((Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties fax).Fax) { }` for the `$null` case.

Answer (score 1):

1. `if(Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties fax -eq $null)` - This is wierd.

I think you should do

```
$user = Get-ADUser $user.samaccountname -Properties fax
if (($null -ne $user) -or ($null -eq $user.fax)) {
```

2. There is no `fax` attribute in AD by default, but [otherfacsimiletelephonenumber](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-otherfacsimiletelephonenumber) exists. It's preferred to use while setting, because you never know how exactly Cmdlets will interpret it.
3. Why you use `if` to check if `fax -eq $null` ? If there is no fax, you add it, and if there is, you replace it. Why not to replace always ?
4. Use pipelines

---

Among all, you should not check if user exists or fax exists, because you overwrite it, this results in one-liner:

```
Import-Csv C:\Csv.csv |
    ForEach-Object {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.samaccountname -Replace @{'otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber'=$_.fax}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

The reason I was trying to use an If statement is because AD Powershell won't let me use -Replace if there is already something in the users' Fax field. My thought process was to check if theres something in the Fax field, if not I would use the -Add cmdlet and if there is, I'd use the -Replace cmdlet. 

After modifying and executing your above command, I was able to run through a test list and replace anyone's fax field that had something in there. For the others without something in their fax field, I got this error: 
Set-ADUser : replace